# Replace visual block with newline without entering insert mode

Tags: vim

How can I replace the selected visual block with a new line without entering insert mode?

From:

```
Hello████World
```

to

```
Hello
World
```

I tried `d` + `r` + `enter`

but I get:

```
Hello
orld
```

I also tried `\r` + 'enter'
and I get:

```
Hello^M^M^M^MWorld
```

What am I missing?

Comment: And would you care to explain why you want to avoid insert mode?

Comment: I'd like to avoid the extra step of pushing `ESC` when using vim's record macro. It keeps messing me up when I forget to push `ESC` to keep moving through code and I have to re-record my macro. Very annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works only from visual block mode and you need at [least patch 7.4.065](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/wMNHIuZcGRQ/iPdMDpibp9wJ) for that (so with a newer version, block select the space, press `r<enter>`)

Comment: Ugh, 7.4.052 is the latest in my repo right now. I think I'm just going to wait for a higher build stable version...

Comment: No problem. I'll try to improve Vim little by little ;)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Thanks; your efforts are much appreciated by the Vim user and dev communities!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `c<enter>`; it works for me.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without entering insert mode?

Comment: Good question. `r` alone doesn't seem to do it, as you pointed out, and I'm not sure why. `dr` doesn't work because `d` deletes the selection and then `r` replaces the "W".

Comment: Edited the question to be more clear on the exact expected behaviour, though `c<Enter>` helps a tad more so thanks for that tidbit.

Comment: No sweat! I'll let you know if I stumble across anything.

Comment: Looks like I was right on the money... the problem seems to be vim itself (check out other answer) :)